# How to set crop image view for PHAsset array in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, phasset

I use multiple imagepicker framework for select image(Set maximum 5 image) but it not have cropimage function how to crop image view like

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
```

thanks